# mat-table sort not working with object path key

Tags: angular, sorting, mat-table

My data that I want to use with mat-table isn't flat - there are layers of different objects.  I can display the data fine but the sorting isn't working.  Here is an example using the element data with the fields sitting down one layer inside a 'foo' object.  How can I get the sorting working?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8u3zr?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {foo: {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'}},
  {foo: {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'}},
  {foo: {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'}},
  ...
```

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="foo.position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.foo.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  ...

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api) (check api tab, and search for sort customization)

> Allows for sort customization by overriding sortingDataAccessor, which
>   **defines how data properties are accessed**. Also allows for filter
>   customization by overriding filterTermAccessor, which defines how row
>   data is converted to a string for filter matching.

So that's what you need, you need to add sortData function of type
`sortData: ((data: T[], sort: MatSort) => T[])`

here is an example

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.sortData = this.sortData;
  }
  sortData(data: PeriodicElement[],sort: MatSort): PeriodicElement[] {
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
  const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
  switch (sort.active) {
    // Add other cases (columns)
    // if you are wondering where is this 'position' coming from, check the html tag for the th below 
    case 'position': return isAsc ? 
    (a.foo.position - b.foo.position > 1 ? 1 : -1)  : 
    (a.foo.position - b.foo.position > 1 ? -1 : 1);
     default: return 0;
  }
});
}}
```

HTML

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header='position'> No. </th>
```